# Why isn't numpy creating *NEW* random values?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to make a list with 6 random values but these values aren't changing each time i run the code.

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)
sizes = rng.integers(low=0,high=500,size=6)
print(sizes)
```

Comment: You are using the same seed for the generator every time. Why do you think it will emit different sequences with the same seed?

Answer (score 1):

working as intended. The number you put here `np.random.default_rng(12345)` is a seed, as long as the seed is the same then the "random" generator will preform the same. If you just remove that number you will get a fresh seed every time.